# UIView Animate only animates if it's in a IBAction. How do I get it to animate in my situation?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func pickWash() {

    bottomChange = self.mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -350.0)
    bottomChange.isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.waterlessLabel.isHidden = false
        self.exteriorInterior.isHidden = false
        self.exteriorOnly.isHidden = false
        self.info.isHidden = false
        self.blackLine.isHidden = false
        self.extIntPrice.isHidden = false
        self.extPrice.isHidden = false
        self.confirmWash.isHidden = false
        self.when.isHidden = false
        self.timeChoice.isHidden = false

    }, completion: nil)

}

func tester(){
   self.pickWash()
}
```

In actuality, my tester method in my code is using Google's Place autocomplete iOS, but I did not want to flood my code with useless autocomplete code. Thus, when the user is done entering their location in Google's autocomplete, the function pickwash() is called and the animate does not work. It only worked for me when I had it in an IBAction with a button. Any idea?

Comment: `isHidden` is not an animatable property. Change the `alpha` instead.

Comment: Are these views onscreen while you're trying to animate them?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted code by accident. I updated my code. I was animating a constraint. Basically half of my map view disappeared so I could add all these different objects in this new white space. It worked in IBAction as I said previously.

Comment: No they are not. They are hidden until this new white space is created, which is why I make them appear. I was trying to animate the white space that appears.

Comment: "It only worked in an IBAction" might suggest `pickWash()` is being called on a thread other than the main one, the only one where you should modify UI elements

Comment: Are you trying to animate the bottom constraint of your `self.mapView` instance?

Comment: @MarcoBoschi That makes sense. I use Google's Auto Complete and once the user selects their address the function is called which means it is on another thread. How do I guarantee that it is called on the Main thread?

Comment: @Pranay Correct.

Comment: @EricAgredo Look at my answer below. if you want to animate a constraint, you should set the set the `constant` property instead of setting the `isActive` property like you have in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickWash()` is being on a thread other than the main one (as confirmed in OP comments) and since the main thread is the only one allowed to work on the UI the behaviour is undefined (here nothing happens). You have to move your code execution to the main thread using

```
func pickWash() {
    // Code here is on a non-main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Code here is executed on the main thread 
        bottomChange = self.mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -350.0)
        bottomChange.isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.waterlessLabel.isHidden = false
            self.exteriorInterior.isHidden = false
            self.exteriorOnly.isHidden = false
            self.info.isHidden = false
            self.blackLine.isHidden = false
            self.extIntPrice.isHidden = false
            self.extPrice.isHidden = false
            self.confirmWash.isHidden = false
            self.when.isHidden = false
            self.timeChoice.isHidden = false

        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

func tester(){
   self.pickWash()
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The Google Autocomplete goes on another thread, which is why it didn't work how I set it up, correct? Do you recommend any resource to better understand what specific things should be running on different threads?

Comment: Exactly, modifying the UI from a thread other than the main one doesn't work (or works unexpectedly). You can look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html for starter, also it's good practice to move any resource intensive task to a background thread to avoid blocking the main thread, which will result in a non-responsive app.

Answer (score 1):

`isHidden` can't be animated use `alpha`, see the below code.
and I noticed that you are setting the time to 10.0 and 10 is so long.

```
func pickWash() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.waterlessLabel.alpha = 1
        self.exteriorInterior.alpha = 1
        self.exteriorOnly.alpha = 1
        self.info.alpha = 1
        self.blackLine.alpha = 1
        self.extIntPrice.alpha = 1
        self.extPrice.alpha = 1
        self.confirmWash.alpha = 1
        self.when.alpha = 1
        self.timeChoice.alpha = 1

    }, completion: nil)

}

func tester(){
   self.pickWash()
}
```

Comment: I used 10 for testing purposes to see how it would animate what I wanted. The comments in my original post reflect that I was animating my constraint. My code has been edited to reflect this already.

Comment: The alpha needs to be set to 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate a constraint, all you have to do is update the constant property. Here's some sample code:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var mapViewBottomConstraint; // If you are not using InterfaceBuilder, then hold a reference to the bottom constraint when you add it to your view.

func pickWash() -> Void {
    self.mapViewBottomConstraint.constant = -350.0; // or whatever is appropriate here.
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        // do your stuff
    }, completion: nil)
}
```